# PHP Adodb many sleeping connections

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

Currently struggeling with a strange problem:
while using adodb as connection layer for php, it leaves many sleeping and unneeded connections behind. `wait_timeout` is set to `20` but there are still plenty (~100) of sleeping connections due to high load on the system. MySQL Version: `5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`

Is there a known bug regarding adodb5 and sleeping connections? I'm *not* using persistent connections! Connection establishment:

```
$conn = &ADONewConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->Connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME)
```

Would really appreciate any hints/suggestions how to reduce sleeping connection count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay finally found the problem:
vhost document root was on an nfs mount (remote). this mount had some IO issues which provoked apache to "idle" connections until the nfs mount is ready again.

Comment: This answer is under-appreciated.  In 99% situations, somebody forgot to explicitly close db connection, but this 1% are freaky system wide issues that are exhausting to debug.

We had situation where Apache webroot was on shared filesystem via GlusterFS v7 and that caused sleep connections to pop up. Updating to glusterfs v8 helped in our particular case. What happened internally is a mystery, because it seemed that glusterfs keeps files open and __destruct in php is never called.

Answer (score 1):

If the snippet is the only thing you do for connecting/disconnecting. Then you most likely just have to close down the connection when you no longer need it.

At most of my php-files I have that use connections this way I have something like following code on the end of the file which opens the connection.

```
<?php
$conn->Close();
?>
```