# debugging slow PHP function querying MYSQL -- sleep ~30 sec

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance

I'm using a scheduling plugin in wordpress (appointments).. but when I retrieve the schedule for a provider, it takes ~30 seconds to load. Granted we have about 100 providers with different schedules.

I looked in the mysql db (show processlist;) and it says "sleep" for ~30 seconds whenever I retrieve a schedule (using json). However, there's no sleep command in the plugin code (actually, there is for the gcal option but I did not activate google calendar).PHP throws no errors, it just takes 30 seconds to load. how can I debug this?
PHP version: 5.4.16

I really don't know how to get to the bottom of this. Whenever there the schedule is retrieved top shows high CPU usage of php-cgi, but I'm not sure if that's abnormal.

```
16943 apache    20   0  540664  68864  20000 R  99.7  1.2   0:53.55 php-cgi
```

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407732/mysql-proccesslist-filled-with-sleep-entries-leading-to-to-many-connections on the meaning of the `sleep` status. In this case it's likely that PHP is reading from the resultset. This is consistent with PHP showing high CPU numbers.

Comment: I should add, I don't have a lot of sleep processes. But whenever the schedule is retrieved there is one sleep process for 30 seconds, but it also ends once the schedule was successfully (but slowly) retrieved.

Comment: Yes, so your bottleneck is in PHP. I think you know enough to start debugging.