# Laravel jobs/queue are adding unnecessary MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, amazon-rds

I am getting the below error from AWS RDS because of so many connections.

> "Too Many Connections"

when I try to debug this issue I run the below command in my MySQL server

```
"SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;"
```

This command shows me 120 MySQL connections and 80 of them are on sleep mode.

After research, I found this is because of the command which runs every 30 minutes on my worker server to schedule email.

How can I reduce this MySQL sleep connection?

Comment: too many sleep connection might be due to the heavy query or long query. Refer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407732/mysql-proccesslist-filled-with-sleep-entries-leading-to-too-many-connections

Comment: Perhaps you are not closing your connections in your script.

Comment: @halfer that is automatically managed by laravel